# jString define compilation error

Tags: android-ndk, nsstring, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am working with JNI.
I tried to define one jstring into project main.cpp file.
I tried to use below one but when I tried to compile with NDK.
I will show error.

```
jstring message = (*jni)->NewStringUTF(jni, "Hello from CPP");
```

If you have any another way with NSString, or String please let me know.

Comment: Did you include `#include <jni.h>`

Answer (score 1):

What error message did you get?

Since you're working in C++ and not in C, the call your're doing should be:

```
jni->NewStringUTF("Hello from CPP");
```

instead of

```
(*jni)->NewStringUTF(jni, "Hello from C");
```